# Camry 2007 4 cylinder. Fuel filter question

Tags: toyota, camry, fuel-filter

Where is the fuel filter located and how often does it have to be changed? I heard that it is part of the fuel pump and to replace one you must replace the other. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true, the good news is they do not need to be changed and last the life of the fuel pump.